# MySQL OSX innodb_force_recovery keeps changing to 1

Tags: mysql

I'm battling with this and have been for a few days..

I have access to my.cnf and have noticed **innodb_force_recovery** keeps appearing. I have removed the line altogether but each time MySQL starts it comes back as follows:

[mysqld]

**innodb_force_recovery = 1**

This is a little out of my depth, I must have changed something somewhere but I'm unable to import an .sql backup to my local Database.

OSX, running MAMP

Can I ask also, how this works, is the problem locally within my Database configuration or is it something that has happened to the table structure we are trying to import?

Thanks

Comment: set innodb_force_recovery = 0 then in the my.cnf?

Comment: Tried that, just resets.. however I’ve found the answer mate. It’s an altered template file in MAMP..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a template file that MAMP uses of all things.